# Update SQL query in flask not working with floating/decimal points

Tags: html, sql, flask, web, decimal-point

So, fairly new in here. Im trying to build a web application that simulates the act of "buying shares".

Everything ok, getting the value, working with it until i need to update the value of cash (the money the user has to spend). So, when I buy a stock, it shows the correct price, but when subtracting that value it rounds up on the SQL table.

[image: this is the picture of the summary ive built]

This is the part of the code that updates the values. I can't get it to show 2 floating points.

```
    @app.route("/")
    @login_required
    def index():
        """Show portfolio of stocks"""
        # Get the user ID
        user_id = session.get('user_id', None)
        # Get the symbol. Query first on stocks SQL
        dictionary = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(shares), company FROM buy_stocks WHERE userid=(:userid) GROUP BY company", userid = user_id)
        # Get the number to iterate on the HTML template
        iterate = len(dictionary)
        symbol = [None] * len(dictionary)
```

(continues and in the end:)

```
    for i in range(len(dictionary)):
            value = int( 100 * price[i] * shares[i] )
            value_temp = value / 100
            total[i] = value_temp
    # Cash still avaiable for more transactions. Sum the total and subtract to the money the user still has
    cash_query = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id=(:userid)", userid = user_id)
    cash = cash_query[0]["cash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this was to extract the values to another function, and workk them there, forcing them to have 2 decimal places.

That did the trick, however, still trying to figure out how can't they be worked from the main function itself.